# Create google doc in google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am able to create text and .doc files in the Google drive using the Google drive API. but when i set the mime type as `application/vnd.google-apps.document` the app crashes with log

> May not create shortcut files using this method. Use
>   DriveFolder.createShortcutFile() instead

This is how try to create the file

```
MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
.setTitle("New file")
.setMimeType("application/msword")// this works
//.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.document") //this does not work
.setStarred(true).build();


Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
.createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, null /* DriveContents */)
.setResultCallback(fileCallback);
```

Is it possible to create google documents from the Drive API ?

Comment: Looking at the [Create Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-create#create_a_shortcut_to_a_file) for the web service, the Mime Type is similar to creating shortcuts (which is what the logs is indicating). I see nothing wrong with how you create the file currently. If you want to read more about it, you can check out the [Creating Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file) in the Drive API for Android documentation

Comment: Google documents are not true documents, they are virtual and are not stored in the drive folder area.

Comment: @Brianfromstatefarm so its impossible to create a new google doc file using API?

Comment: When working with c# and a REST API I found out attempting to pull files that there is a separate call to request a google docs file.  Basically one has to tell google docs to convert the file to an output format.  I am looking for a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use `application/vnd.google-apps.file` for the creating?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are trying this with the Metadatachangeset class.
This class is, like the name says, better used for getting metadata of files.

To create/insert a new file you should use the class File.

Here an example: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#examples

Very helpful might be this link. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Your mime_type ".document" should be correct. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/mime-types