# I want to create spreadsheet on google drive programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Following code i am using for creating spreadsheet.

```
MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setTitle("New file")
                    //.setMimeType("text/plain")
                    .setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet")
                    .setStarred(true).build();

            // create a file on root folder
            Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                    .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, driveContents)
                    .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
```

If I use Mime type `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` then it's showing an error and not creating any spreadsheet. And if I use Mime type `text/plain` then it creating a file. So please help me ...

Following error is coming when I tried for creating google spreadsheet:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2475
      Process: com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo, PID: 31762
      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: May not create shortcut files using this method. Use DriveFolder.createShortcutFile() instead.
                  at com.google.android.gms.drive.internal.zzy.zzb(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.drive.internal.zzy.createFile(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo.CreateFileActivity$1$1.run(CreateFileActivity.java:82)
```

Comment: If sheet is not created than please post error message. You can refer https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/ for adding and putting value in a spreadsheet.

Comment: what's the error? Your mime type is corect.

Comment: please give me solution guys....

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745531/create-google-doc-in-google-drive) if it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do this.

The create file method is something like this:

```
Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                    .createFile

if (mimeType.equals("application/vnd.google-apps.folder") || mimeType.startsWith("application/vnd.google-apps")) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("May not create shortcut files using this method. Use DriveFolder.createShortcutFile() instead.);
}
```

To do this you will have to use the REST API https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/